# Is using echo rather than printf a trouble maker for string translation using .pot file and Poedit?

Tags: php, wordpress, translate, poedit

I was wondering could the use of `echo` in php code rather than the use of `printf()` be the cause of a .mo file or in general the reason why the translation files do not work at all?

**For Example**:

In my php code I have this line of code: 
`echo __('Twinkle Twinkle little star');`

Which has the double underscore identifier `__()`.

When using [Poedit](https://poedit.net/), I get my string displayed in the translatable strings column, so that's not an issue.

**Sum up**: 
Could echo cause a problem with the translation even thought Poedit can index and understand that the string is there?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: @rickdenhaan make sure to write this as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` and `printf` are not related to translations. They are merely ways to output a string.

The translating is performed by the `__()` function. So assuming you have your locale set to French with the proper files loaded:

```
echo "Hello";
// Hello
echo __("Hello");
// Bonjour

printf("Hello");
// Hello
printf(__("Hello"));
// Bonjour
```